# How do I use Vista's "query process" with a long program name?

Tags: windows-vista

I'm trying to use Vista's process list utility to find a PID. You should be able to do this:

```
query process program.exe
```

What I'm finding is that if the program name is short (like above), it will find it. But if it's long, like the following:

```
query process notificationmanager.exe
```

it won't find it. The length in question seems to be the display length of the query process command itself, which is 12 characters.

Is there a special syntax for specifying long program names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

query process notificationmanager

Note, it isn't a matter of dropping the .exe, but rather just take the first 19 characters.

A consequence of this, is that it will return all processes whose name starts with notificationmanager.

Answer (score 1):

Does it work if you put the program name in double quotes, e.g.:

```
query process "notificationmanager.exe"
```

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

if you can use wmic then

wmic process where "name = 'notificationmanager.exe' list brief